Trouble solving json response cache issue in Laravel
I am unable to get a exchange rates converter json API result to cache in laravel.
I have tried a lot actually - too much to post on here.
But at this moment this is the code:
<?php

namespace App\Tools;

class Converter
{
    /**
     * Convert USD to authenticated user currency
     * @param  float $amount
     * @param  string $to, from
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public static function currencyConverter($amount, $to, $from = 'USD')
    {
        $content = \Cache::remember('exchange_price', 3600, function() 
        {
          file_get_contents("https://api.exchangerate.host/v1/convert?access_key=myaccesskeygoeshere&from=$from&to=$to&amount=$amount");
          $respost = json_decode($content, true);
          $price = $respost['result'];
        });
        return number_format($price, 2);
    }

The error I am getting at the moment is:

ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable $from at
/app/Tools/Converter.php:16)

Can anybody please point me in the right direction?
I thank you all a lot :-)

Because you have an anonymous function inside another function, you need to bring the variables you want back into scope with use. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/16959577/231316

Also, unless my coffee hasn't kicked in correctly and I'm missing something, anonymous functions do not have an implicit return, so you'd need return somewhere. The alternative is to switch it to an arrow function which both captures and implicitly returns.

Further, $price only lives inside the anonymous function, I think return number_format($price, 2) should be return number_format($content , 2)

Thanks for the pointers, like i mentioned before far from a genius here, trying to learn but it's not easy :).
When changing '''number_format($price, 2)''' to '''return number_format($content , 2)''' it causes an error and the exchanger stops working.
Reading the post you gave in the first message now.

The formatting of the code makes it hard to follow. I've broken things unto multiples lines to make it easier read: https://3v4l.org/3mV6q. (Format how you want, I've just done it for the sake of communication here.) All three lines in the anonymous function might throw an exception or raise a warning, so you should probably add some guards there, too. This code isn't tested, and I don't know Laravel, so I'm just looking at it from a PHP perspective only.

Regardless i thank you a lot for your advice and help.
I have multiple other things getting cached in my application and those work fine, but somehow with this function i am unable to get it cached and its really taking up resources.

Wait... coffee is kicking in more. I don't think you want to cache this at all. The only thing you'd want to cache is an exchange rate between two currencies for a limited period of time maybe. The only reason to cache this is if you think lots of people are going to try to convert the same amount over and over again. In that case, all three variables should be included in the cache key, too, and then your cache key would be something like sprintf('exchange_price_convert_%s_to_%s_from_%s', $amount, $to, $from). You should probably normalize $amount before doing that, too.

Ok, but this is actually a function that is reflected on product prices and there are a lot of products.
So when products get loaded on a page the prices are taken from USD (standard setting of user) to the user his/her selected display currency.

Okay. The rules for caching are generally whether a function is relatively expensive to call, and/or it will be called multiple times. So as long as your business logic maps to that, caching makes sense. But whatever you provide to the function, those should almost always be included in the cache key, too.

Maybe it would be smarter if i tried caching not the $to and $from but just make a API call for all possible exchange currencies in the available currencies and cache those from USD to all of them once a hour as example.

Does your API support getting a multiplier or some sort? If so, if you can get "USD to JPY = 144.63", and get that in bulk, that's what I think makes the most sense.

something important to note, this will cache all calls to this api. no matter the amount or the conversion targets

As already spotted this a php problem $from does not exists into the anonymous function, it'not a laravel problem. I'm not sure if laravel can handle dynamic parameters in anonymous function in his cache::remember tho.
Anyway you'd better separate your API call into a separate method or service and add some error handling for file_get_contents, json_decode and test the existence of your result.
